# Rails 3 - Vanity URL based on user attribute that displays a static page

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to implement vanity url's in my rails app. I have a url attribute in my user model. So when someone navigates to mycoolapp.com/ they are routed to a static page that will get specific user info based on the url and display that on the page. I looked at the vanity URL gem, but am not sure that will work for me. Right now I have this manually implemented like this...

```
#config/routes
  get 'tommystavern', to: 'static_pages#tommystavern', as: 'tommystavern'

#app/controllers/static_pages_controller.rb
  def tommystavern
    @events = Event.find_all_by_user_id 2
  end

#app/views/static_pages/tommystavern.html.erb
<h1>Tommy's Tavern events</h1>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Title</th>
    <th>Starts at</th>
    <th>Description</th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
  </tr>

<% @events.each do |event| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= event.title %></td>
    <td><%= event.starts_at %></td>
    <td><%= event.description %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
</table>
```

I would like to have a 'smart' route in my controller that would find the URL in my User.url attribute, then send that to a general page like app/views/static_pages/home.html.erb that would display user events based on the URL. Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What if you were to use your Users in the routes file like so:

```
User.all.each do |user|
  get user.url, to: 'static_pages#user_profile', :id => user.id
end
```

And then in your controller:

```
def user_profile
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  @events = Event.find_all_by_user_id @user.id
end
```

And then in your view:

```
<h1><%= @user.name %> events</h1>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Title</th>
    <th>Starts at</th>
    <th>Description</th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
  </tr>

  <% @events.each do |event| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= event.title %></td>
      <td><%= event.starts_at %></td>
      <td><%= event.description %></td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

That works...in the mean time here is what I did...

```
#config/routes.rb
  get '/:website', :controller => 'static_pages', :action => 'vanity'

#app/controllers/static_pages_controller.rb
  def vanity
      @user = User.find_by_website(params[:website])
    if @user != nil #in case someone puts in a bogus url I redirect to root
      @events = @user.events
    else
      redirect_to :root
    end
  end

#app/views/static_pages/vanity.html.erb
<h1><%= @user.website  %> events</h1>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Title</th>
    <th>Starts at</th>
    <th>Description</th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
  </tr>

<% @events.each do |event| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= event.title %></td>
    <td><%= event.starts_at %></td>
    <td><%= event.description %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
</table>
```